# combine vectors into df, and turn vector names into rows of a new column

Tags: r, vector

I want to combine N vectors into a data frame that includes a column where the values are the names of the original vectors. For example, say I have these three vectors:

```
fruits <- c('apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'raspberry')
vehicles <- c('cars', 'bikes', 'buses', 'trains')
weather <- c('sunny', 'windy', 'rainy', 'cloudy', 'cold', 'hot')
```

I can get halfway to what I want by using `enframe` from the tidyverse. E.g.

```
enframe(c(fruits, vehicles, weather), name = "name", value = "value")

# A tibble: 14 × 2
    name value    
   <int> <chr>    
 1     1 apple    
 2     2 pear     
 3     3 banana   
 4     4 raspberry
 5     5 cars     
 6     6 bikes    
 7     7 buses    
 8     8 trains   
 9     9 sunny    
10    10 windy    
11    11 rainy    
12    12 cloudy   
13    13 cold     
14    14 hot
```

But what I want now is a new column that contains the names of the three vectors from which the elements come from. E.g.

```
# A tibble: 14 × 2
    name value    
   <chr> <chr>    
  fruits apple    
  fruits pear     
  fruits banana   
  fruits raspberry
vehicles cars     
vehicles bikes    
vehicles buses    
vehicles trains   
 weather sunny    
 weather windy    
 weather rainy    
 weather cloudy   
 weather cold     
 weather hot
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem; sure you could get the names of the variables from your environment, store them in a `list` and then bind the vectors and their names in such a way that it reproduces your expected output. But how are `fruits`, `vehicles` and `weather` generated in the first place? Rather than having three separate vectors, 
 which is awkward, it would be better if they were in a named `list` to start with. That's what where I would start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` after `mget`.

```
stack(mget(c("fruits", "vehicles", "weather")))
#      values      ind
#1      apple   fruits
#2       pear   fruits
#3     banana   fruits
#4  raspberry   fruits
#5       cars vehicles
#6      bikes vehicles
#7      buses vehicles
#8     trains vehicles
#9      sunny  weather
#10     windy  weather
#11     rainy  weather
#12    cloudy  weather
#13      cold  weather
#14       hot  weather
```